# LINQ: latest sum of data within data range

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a snapshot table in my database that holds historical data of appointment availability.

I'm trying to write a LINQ query to get the total number of AvailableSlots within a given date range from the latest snapshot.

Here is what my table looks like:

[image]

So with this given data, I'd want my LINQ query to return the sum of AvailableSlots within the date range of 2018-01-01 - 2018-01-02 and with the latest SnapShotTime. So, I'd expect the query to return 4.

Here is what I have so far.

```
var test = db.snapshots
      .GroupBy(g =>
         g.AppointmentTime >= startDate &&
         g.AppointmentTime <= endDate
      ).Select(s => s.OrderByDesending(x => x.SnapShotTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

However, I'm not sure how to put the Sum of available slots into this LINQ query. Any help on writing this query would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `GroupBy` should be a `Where`, and then you should group by SnapShotTime and take the sum of the highest group. Although I think you should group by the minute or seconds  part of SnapShotTime? Can they really be equal to the millisecond?

Comment: What does "20:0101:137" represent?

Comment: @NetMage, that's just the time stamp from the DateTime column

Comment: @GertArnold, how would I group by the minute?

Comment: That depends on the data type of `SnapShotTime`. Its uncommon (to me) format makes me wonder whether it's DateTime.

Comment: What type of timestamp is `20:0101:137`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont see exactly the query that you wrote do, but based on your explanation i think sth like this might have work

```
var query=db.snapshots
              .Where(x=>x.AppointmentTime >= startDate &&
                     x.AppointmentTime <= endDate)
              .GroupBy(x=>x.SnapShotTime)
              .OrderByDesending(g=>g.Key)
              .Take(1)
              .Sum(x=>x.Value.AvailableSlots);
```

or if it seems so complicated you better first get the latest date like this

```
var latest=db.snapshots
            .OrderByDesending(x => x.SnapShotTime)
            .FirstOrDefault().SnapShotTime;
```

and then get your count like this

```
var query=db.snapshots
           .Where(x=>x.AppointmentTime >= startDate &&
                     x.AppointmentTime <= endDate   &&
                     x.SnapShotTime==latest)
            .Sum(x=>x.AvailableSlots);
```

Comment: There is no definition for Value

Comment: I ended up going with something similar to this, but added the following to the end: .Sum(x => (int?)x.AvailableSlots) ?? 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
        DateTime endDate = new DateTime();

        List<FakeAppointments> appointmentsFromDatabase = new List<FakeAppointments>();

        var appointmentsBetweenStartDateAndEndDate = appointmentsFromDatabase.Where(p => p.SnapshotTime >= startDate && p.SnapshotTime <= endDate).ToList();
        int sum = appointmentsBetweenStartDateAndEndDate.Sum(p => p.AvailableSlots);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class FakeAppointments
    {
        public DateTime SnapshotTime;
        public int AvailableSlots;
    }
```